# port number in server

Tags: c#

I am now using the default port number `TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(9999);`
but because at my client side, i have put a textbox to allow user to manually key in the port number. So how do i make my server side to allow port number from port 1 to 9999 instead

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(9999);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        int counter = 0;

        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to NYP Chat Server ");
        counter = 0;
        while ((true))
        {
            counter += 1;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;

            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

            clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

            broadcast(dataFromClient + " Connected ", dataFromClient, false);

            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " has join the chat room ");
            handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
        {
            TcpClient broadcastSocket;
            broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.Value;
            NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

            if (flag == true)
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg);
            }
            else
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }

            broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
            broadcastStream.Flush();
        }
    }  //end broadcast function
}//end Main class


public class handleClinet
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    Hashtable clientsList;

    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)
    {
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        this.clientsList = cList;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }

    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }//end while
    }//end doChat
  } //end class handleClinet
}//end namespace
```

Comment: You should restrict ports to be greater than 1024: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Adding to Rubens comment, *nix won't let a user other than root use registered ports.  DNS requests take place over port 53 UDP (TCP for DNS servers doing transfers), 25 is for SMTP (email) etc.  Stick to the unregistered region.

Answer (score 1):

Add a setting to your program so that you can change the port...

Project properties -> Settings tab -> create a setting called PortNumber, of type Int32, with a default value of 9999

In your code, retrieve the value with `Properties.Settings.Default.PortNumber`

---

EDIT: I misread the question. Do you want to listen to all ports from 1 to 9999 at the same time ?? It doesn't make sense, because

1. many ports in that range will already be used by other processes
2. you don't *need* to listen on so many ports...

If you're worried about having multiple users connected at the same time, that's not an issue : just use a new thread to handle each incoming connection, and call `AcceptTcpClient` again on the listener on the main thread.

Comment: "you don't need to listen on so many ports" - unless you're `inetd` :-)

Comment: erm what i mean is, actually allowing the user at client side to manually choose 1 port number from the range number of 0 - 9999.

Comment: You need to choose this on the server side - the server has to be listening already for the client to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to make the port number customizable via the [application configuration file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374182(VS.85).aspx).
  This would allow the server to change ports without a recompilation.

As far as the code goes, you just need to set the port to use here:

```
TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(portFromAppConfig);
```

Also, you shouldn't use ports lower than 1024 - these are reserved ports for system services.  You should stick to ports in the higher range of numbers (in general).

Comment: where can i find the application configuration file?

Comment: It'll be app.config during debug, and yourprogram.exe.config at deployment time.  See the link I posted for details.

Answer (score -1):

You don't normally have a single server listening on multiple ports; it's fairly strange. What you do is accept connections, and then pass them off for processing in another thread, and go back to accepting more connections.